# Is it correct his statement of the third law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Is the statement "If $T\to 0$ then $S\to 0$" meaningfull? To speack about variation of entropy (or about entropy, having choosen a reference state) we must calculate Clausius integral in a reversible trasformation between two states. But the state of a system cannot be defined only by temperature, so third law (and absolute entropy) looks meaningless...

Comment: The "3rd" does not say that "If $T\to 0$ then $S\to 0$"  instead if "If $T\to 0$ then $S\to const$ and it is so *independently* of any other parameter the system may depend on, in other words the other variables that otherwise would matter are frozen in, so to speak, at $T=0$ and has no effect on the entropy. When phrased this way it is is *meaningful*.

Comment: so if the temperature is low enough the state of the system is completely defined by the temperature, or at least all the states tend to have the same entropy, interesting.

Comment: there are some obvious paradoxes with the usual claim that "$S \to 0$", e.g., you have a mixture of two chemical species, then you must have some configurational entropy that remains and cannot be zero at any temperature as $T \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third law of thermodynamics states, "The entropy of a system approaches a constant value as its temperature approaches absolute zero."

This constant entropy, $S_0$ must be independent of any other state variables, like pressure, volume, applied magnetic field, etc.  No matter what the starting state, as $T\rightarrow 0$ the same $S\rightarrow S_0$ is reached.

$T=0$ is the minimum energy state of the system.  If $S_0=0$, then there is a unique minimum energy state (ground state) for the system.  This is a consequence of the statistical mechanics definition of entropy,
$$S = k_B \log\Omega, $$
where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates corresponding to the observed macrostate.
$$ \Omega = 1 \implies S = k_B \log 1 = 0$$

If there are multiple microstate configurations that correspond to the same $T=0$ macrostate, then $S_0 \ne 0$.